# Cannot assign to 'let' value 'action'

Tags: switch-statement, swift, constants

I'm trying to define a constant outside a switch statement so that I can use it after the switch statement is done executing and assign it within the switch statement:

```
let action: SKAction!

switch (whatever) {
case 0:
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, self.scene.size.height * lengthDiceroll)
    action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width, self.scene.size.height * (1 - lengthDiceroll)), duration: 1) // error here
    // other actions
default:
    println("meh")       

// add the sprite to the scene
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action, action2])
sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
self.addChild(sprite)
```

But I'm getting the error `Cannot assign to 'let' value 'action'`. How do I assign to action so that I can use it outside of the switch?

If I try:

```
action! = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width, self.scene.size.height * (1.0 - lengthDiceroll)), duration: 1)
```

I get the error `"Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables declared with `let` must immediately be assigned a value. You cannot simply define a variable with let and no value like you're trying to do on the first line.

You say you want action to be a constant, but you are modifying its value at runtime, which is not what a constant is. Thus, you need a variable, even if its value only changes once.

Comment: “The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once. This means you can use constants to name a value that you determine once but use in many places.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: What they mean by not known at compile time means they can depend on the value of another variable or function. What they don't explicitly state in the iBook is that let declarations must have an initial value expression.

Comment: @JuJoDi the two statements are not mutually exclusive, for example `let foo = someFunctionThatComputesFoo()`.

Comment: Example: `let x: Int = random(betweenValue:15, andOtherValue:30)` is only set once, but the value is non-deterministic.

Comment: Actually, the constant is assigned a value at the declaration -- it's an optional, so the value is implicitly `nil`. You need to declare it as a variable.

Comment: Counter-example: `let x: Int; x = 2` gives the following compile-time error: `'let' declarations require an initializer expression`

Comment: @Lukas is correct. `let action: SKAction!` is assigning the value `nil` to `action`

Comment: It should be noted that there is an exception. Constants in classes aren't assigned initial values. If the value is set in `init`, that value is used. If it isn't set in `init`, `nil` is used, or if the constant is not an optional it's a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution here: [Assign conditional expression in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315698/assign-conditional-expression-in-swift)

> You can use a closure to initialize an immutable:

```
let foo: Int = {
    if bar == 2 {
        return 100
    } else {
        return 120
    }
}()
```

You can use switch, another functions and any complex logic inside the closure.