# Assign conditional expression in Swift?

Tags: swift

1. Is there a way in Swift to assign conditional expressions similar to this:

```
let foo = if (bar == 2) {
    100
} else {
    120
}
```

2. Can it be done using `switch/case`?

**Note 1:** I do **NOT** want to have to use the ternary operator for this).

This kind of assignment is good for functional style / immutability. The expressions have a return value in this case.

**Note2:** it's a general question, this is just a simplified example, imagine e.g. a switch case with a lot of values, pattern matching, etc. You can't do that with the ternary operator.

BTW, also note that there are languages (like [Scala](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax)) that don't support the ternary operator because if else returns a value, so it's not necessary.

Comment: ‘Don't want to have to use ternary operator for this’ What?! Why?

Comment: Because ternary operator can become quickly unreadable and is rather unflexible (compared to switch case at least).

Comment: why not: `let foo = (bar == 2) ? 100 : 120`?

Comment: @lxx That comment made me cry. The answer to the question is a ternary operator.

Comment: @holex Because apparently that's ‘unreadable’ and ‘un[sic]flexible‘... *sigh*

Comment: @Biffen, then why not `var foo` then an `if...else...` statement after?

Comment: @holex That was OP's opinion. *I* am *all for* a ternary.

Comment: @Biffen, I'd go for a ternary operator too, that is a kinda silly and subjective statement if something is found _unreadable_... it is not real issue or argument (from the OP), but a personal suffer only. :)

Comment: @Biffen it's a general question, my snippet is just an example - imagine a switch case with a lot of possible values, pattern matching, etc.

Comment: @lxx OK. Good that you edited the question to point that out.

Comment: I think the language I used suggests that it's a general question: "similar to...", "this kind of...", "the expressions have a return value". It seems it was not clear enough though.

Comment: This is a clear question and yes the ternary operator is not the answer for many/most cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a closure to initialize an immutable:

```
let foo: Int = {
    if bar == 2 {
        return 100
    } else {
        return 120
    }
}()
```

The advantage of using a closure is that it's a function, so you can use any complex logic inside, implemented in a clean way and not through nested ternary operators. It can be a `switch` statement, it can be obtained as the return value of a function followed by some calculations, it can be a pattern matching case, it can be a combination of them all, etc.

Said in other words, it's the same as initializing with the return value of a function, but the difference is that the function is inline and not somewhere else, with readability benefits.

Just for completeness, if the variable is **mutable**, you can use deferred initialization:

```
var foo: Int

// Any statement here

if bar == 2 {
    foo = 100
} else {
    foo = 120
}

// Other statements here

myFunc(foo)
```

so you can declare a mutable variable, and initialize it anywhere in the same scope, but before using it the variable must be initialized.

**Update**: Since Swift 2.0, deferred initialization also works with **immutables**.

Comment: I'm not saying this answer is wrong, but how is either of these better than a ternary?

Comment: It's not better, it's different. If I have 2 options, I prefer the ternary. The closure instead lets you initialize the variable with complex and multiline statements - you can use a `switch`, you can call a function returning a value, do some calculations on it, and return the result, etc.

Comment: Glad to hear neither I nor the world are going insane.

Comment: I edited my question - it was supposed to be generic. This answer helps (the first part), thanks. I prefer it without the return keyword, a bit more succinct imo.

Comment: Woops, sorry. It seems I missed an update of Swift, now return is required. I think there was a time during beta where this was optional.

Comment: Never heard of that... closest thing I've used is the implicit return for single statement closures.

Comment: Ok, I think my memories mixed in another language, I think it's Scala again :) it seems in Swift it was never possible.

Comment: With the current Swift, the "deferred initialization" works for *constants* as well.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5.9 added support for `if` expressions: [SE-0380](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0380-if-switch-expressions.md).

Which would allow the following:

```swift
let foo = 
    if bar == 2 { 100 } 
    else { 120 }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [**Swift 5.9**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0380-if-switch-expressions.md)

if you only have 1 condition to check, you can use a simple `if/else` expression's result as you already posted from Swift 5.9.

The one-liner version would be like:

```
let foo = if (bar == 2) { 100 } else { 120 }
```

For more complicated situations, you can **directly** assign the value from a `switch/case` expression like:

```
let foo = switch bar {
    case 1: "Simple expression"
    case 2: "More" + " " + "complicated" + " " + "Expression"
    case 3: 
        let expression = { /* Very complicated stuff */ }()
        let result = String(describing: expression())
        return result
    default: "All of these are samples"
}
```

For the sake of completeness of the answer, don't forget that you can do `ternary operator` in Swift for simple expressions:

```
let foo = bar == 2 ? 100 : 120
```

<sub>⚠️ Although you can mix the above methods and even use closures,
choose the desired method **based on the complexity of the expression** and try to **keep the code easy to read**.</sub>